# The orthogonal behaviour of a subset of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, rational-numbers

**Notations.**

Let $n\ge 4$ be an integer, $d,e\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ and $j\in\{1,\ldots,\min(d,e)\}$.

We say that a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ is *rational* if it admits a rational basis. We denote by $\mathfrak R_n(e)$ the set of rational subspaces of dimension $e$.

We denote by $\mathfrak I_n(d,e)_j$ the set of subspaces $A$ of $\mathbb R^n$ of dimension $d$ such that

$$\forall B\in\mathfrak R_n(e),\quad \dim(A\cap B)<j.$$

**The question.**

We want to show that if $d+e\leqslant n$ and $j\in\{1,\ldots,\min(d,e)\}$, then

$$A\in\mathfrak I_n(d,e)_j\implies A^\perp\in\mathfrak I_n(n-d,n-e)_j.$$

**What I did.**

I don't know if this result is true, but I can't find a counterexample.

If we assume that there exists $B\in\mathfrak R_n(n-e)$ such that $\dim(A^\perp\cap B)\geqslant j$, then there exists $C$ a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ of dimension $k\geqslant j$ such that

$$A^\perp\cap B=C,$$

then

$$(A^\perp\cap B)^\perp=C^\perp$$

so

$$A+B^\perp=C^\perp,$$

so

$$d+e\leqslant n-j$$

but it does not help that much...

---

Any help or reference to prove or disprove the result would be of great help!

Comment: There are unclear cases in your definition/question because the condition $j \leq \min(d,e)$ is not symmetrical : you can have $j \leq \min(d,e)$ without $j \leq \min(n-d,n-e)$. When you ask whether $A\in\mathfrak I_n(d,e)_j\implies A^\perp\in\mathfrak I_n(n-d,n-e)_j$, you really mean $j \leq \min(n-d,n-e), \ A\in\mathfrak I_n(d,e)_j$ $\implies A^\perp\in\mathfrak I_n(n-d,n-e)_j$, right ? Otherwise, one can construct a trivial counterexample where $d=e=j=n-1$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Thanks for the remark. I added the condition $d+e\le n$ so it should worked.

Comment: Take $d=e=1=j$, $n=4$, $A$ being generated by $(1,\sqrt{2},2,2\sqrt{2})$. Then $A^{\perp} \cap \mathbb{Q}^n$ has dimension at least $2$. In particular there is a rational $3$-dimensional vector subspace such that its intersection with $A^{\perp}$ has dimension $> j$.

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks for the comment!